# Multiple bootstrap modals opening on click despite different data-targets

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, attributes, bootstrap-modal, overlapping

Hi there I'm making a cms with php, some ajax and using bootstrap for the backend design. I'm having a problem with the modals where the second bootstrap modal called is opening the modal before it as well which is not I want.

Just want modal1 to open when data-target="#modal1" is clicked and modal2 to open when data-target="#modal2" without the first appearing as well. 
[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt85z.png)

Any help appreciated.

Code for name from database and edit and delete link for that row from database

---

```
<div class="editAndDelete_box">
        <p" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editLocation-modal" onclick="editLocationDetails('<?php echo $row['regionName'];?>',<?php echo $row['region_ID'];?>, 'Region')">edit</p>
        <!--<a href="region/editRegion.php?region_ID=< ?php echo $row['region_ID']; ?>edit</a>"-->

        <p data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteLocation-modal" onclick="deleteRegiononclick('<?php echo $row['regionName'];?>',<?php echo $row['region_ID'];?>, 'Region')">delete</p>
        <!--<p class="deleteRegion_btn" onclick="window.location.href='javascript:deleteRegion(< ?php echo $row['region_ID']; ?>)'">delete</p>-->
    </div>
```

Modals Code

---

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editLocation-modal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 id="editLocation-title" class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <!--<p id="editLocation-name">Some text in the modal.</p>-->
      <p id="editLocation-message"></p>
      <input id="editLocation-name" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" id="confirmLocationChanges-btn" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
      <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>-->
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteLocation-modal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 id="deleteLocation-title" class="modal-title"></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <!--<p id="deleteLocation-name">Some text in the modal.</p>-->
      <p id="deleteLocation-message"></p>
      <!--<input id="deleteLocation-name" class="form-control" type="text">-->
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" id="deleteLocation-btn" class="btn btn-default btn-error" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
      <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>-->
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please also add the problematic codes. We can't really help you properly without the codes

Comment: @CarlBinalla sorry have just updated now with more details and an image of the current problem experiencing

Comment: You are missing the closing div tag for each modal fade class.